# Android QR code scanner not showing custom protocols

Tags: android, protocols, qr-code

I have observed that the camera-integrated QR scanner in Android only recognizes/resolves specific protocols, e.g. http/s, ftp. In order to open my app, I wanted to use my own protocol, e.g. myapp123://username=james -- this is not being shown, however.

Below you'll find two examples.

1. Working: HTTPS

[image: QR code with https protocol]

2. Not working: custom protocol

[image: QR code with custom protocol]

Is there any way to whitelist my custom protocol, or is there any guideline I can look up?